# Is there a way to update a single service in a DI container with new code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I was wondering if it would theoretically be possible to deploy new code to a c# app using dependency injection while it's running. I could imagine something like:

```
IServiceCollection.UpdateRecursively<IService, Service>();
```

Where the current implementation of IService would be replaced with Service and all Services in the DI container that need IService would be recreated using the new Implementation of Service (and the same would happen with all services that depend on IService recursively).

I don't know much about how code compilation works, but I think this would mean that every Class would have to have its own file of compiled code that could be swapped out at runtime. In this case, Service would have to be recompiled. It would be optimal if all attributes of the recreated Services except those that need to be replaced would be preserved. Could something like this be possible? Is it already a thing? How could the DI container even be accessed from outside the startup class?

Comment: No. You could use Appdomains to unload/load code, but I do not think it would be compatible with a dependency injection container. Unloading code at runtime is really difficult, since you need to remove all objects of types defined in the assembly from memory, and everything that uses a removed object would somehow need to handle the sudden removal. I think COM can do unloading, at the cost of a fair bit of extra complexity.

Comment: I suppose it's possible to do that. Use the factory (IServiceFactory) that will create the service. These links may help: [Create a .NET Core application with plugins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support), [Unloadability in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability), [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: It's very hard to answer your question, because it really depends on what it is you want to achieve. Do you want to let users write C# code on the fly and apply that while the application is running (you'd use the CodeDom or Roslyn). Do you want to drop in compiled code (dlls) into the running application (you load plugin dlls using `Assembly.Load`). Replacing registrations in a created MS.DI `IServiceProvider` is not possible, but there might other feasible options; but it all depends on your use case.